# ReactJS logic for rendering application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, lifecycle

So I am not the best with React. I am building an application that gets user information from an external endpoint and stores it in local storage. I realize that my react-app is loading the html before the state for that data is updated and just doesn't display it in the front end. I would like to have the application wait until those items are in local storage before rendering. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use async and await for that.

```
async componentDidMount(){
   await fetch()....
   /* your code goes here*/
}
```

Comment: By code i mean whatever you are doing after the fetch

Answer (score 0):

Using functional components, you would typically do something like:

```
function App() {
   const [data, setData] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
     // Fetching or other async logic here...
     fetch('/some/url/here')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => setData) // save the result in state
   }, [])

   // Not loaded yet, return nothing.
   if (!data) {
     return null
   }

   // Loaded! return your app.
   return <div>Fetched data: { data.myData }</div>
}
```